# What would cause my script generated buttons and text to show in Unity and not on my phone?

Tags: unity, android, gui, unityscript

I am using Unity 5 and the built in GUI tools.  My static GUI shows up just fine which makes me think it's not a text/font issue or some such. Again, it all looks good in the Unity editor when I hit Play.

I have tried the different canvas options as far as what space to work in and how to scale. I have messed with the build options.  I have tried turning batching off. I have tried building for Android 4 through 5. (Ice Cream, Jelly Bean, etc) I have tried turning dynamic text on and off.  I have ensured the Buttons and text are made to be children of the canvas. I have only uploaded the game onto my Galaxy Note 4. I moved my background texture out of screen space in case it somehow covered the buttons on Android.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hk1UjXwOR08

Comment: Instead of "I'm having a problem, are there any tutorials that cover this subject" you should add additional details about the exact problem you're dealing with now and what you've done to try to solve it. It sounds like you should get more error logging to give you additional information.

Comment: Done and done. Almost completely reworded.

Comment: Given that you say these buttons and text are generated in code, is it possibly as simple as code that runs in the editor but not on device?

Comment: It appears to be that way, yes.  Why would that happen?  Byte56 says I need more error logging and I believe he is right.  I will set up a static text box and... if my scripts wont run.. mind melt. I would write an error logging script but my scripts may not be running.

Comment: One guess: you'd have to set these up deliberately, but maybe you did and forgot? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: Unfortunately no.  All of my code is written by me as well. I haven't partitioned it to only run with certain platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug reported:

Unity does not appear to generate UI elements upon Start.  User input, or possibly some arbitrary amount of time in necessary until the application/game will generate the UI elements.

I made my app wait to generate the buttons until I hit a button and it worked as intended.

I suspect generating the UI from the Update() func would work properly. I would just need to add a bool check for initialization statements

Comment: good catch, tricky use case. Try Invoke() from Start() to see if waiting a bit works.

Comment: As soon as I am home, I will do this.

Comment: Invoke does not appear to help. Tried 3 seconds.

Comment: Also 5 seconds.  No worky.  Surprised im the first to notice. Which is why I still have the inkling I'm just being stupid somewhere.

Comment: Well, I can't imagine many other people are generating the new UI elements from code. In fact, I didn't realize you could. I'd love to see you edit in some of that code into the original question...

Comment: Really? How do people get like text for games, lets say floating damage readout when you hit someone? Or inventory Arrows x 25.  The arrows portion could be a prefab but the number of arrows needs to be dynamic?  Not trying to be an ass.  Legit wondering.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you meant by "script generated buttons and text". The actual UI elements are created ahead of time, not in code, but the string displayed is set at runtime. As in, the inventory display just says "Test x0" in Unity, but the code sets it to "Arrows x25" while the game is running.

Comment: Im making prefabs of buttons and text  and then generating them.

Comment: It's the word "generating" that I'm unclear on. Rather than continuing to discuss this in comments, you should edit code/more details into your original question so that I know what you are talking about.

Comment: It is poorly worded. Thanks.  I will update it soon.